Getting Error on running command "./gradlew signingReport"

enter image description here
In this image the error is shown, please tell me a proper solution for this.

I want to get the SHA-1 and SHA-256 key value by running the "./gradlew signingReport"  command.
What else can be done in this?
I want the SHA key for the firebase project set Up so this is the problem that I'm facing right now.

Instead of running commad at root of your flutter project,
Firstly run cd android at the root of your flutter project and then run ./gradlew signingReport

go to search bar and search signingreport and press enter after that build you will reviece a SHA-1 Key you can get  on there.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Problem:
You are facing an issue because of a mismatch between the google-services library version and your project's Java version. You are also using an outdated way of applying the Flutter Gradle plugin, which is now deprecated.
Steps to fix this:

Update the google-services library version to the latest one in your project. The version you are currently using is outdated and incompatible.

Make sure your project is using Java 8. This will help resolve the Java version conflict.

Apply the Google Services plugin using the new method recommended by Flutter's documentation. The way you are currently applying it is no longer supported.

Clean and rebuild your project to remove any cached issues.

After making these changes, run the ./gradlew signingReport command again to generate the SHA-1 and SHA-256 keys for your Firebase project.


Ensure that all your project dependencies are updated to their latest versions.
If you're still facing issues, check the Flutter breaking changes documentation here for any recent changes that could be affecting your project.
